# Using javascript to highlight syntax in code examples.

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

So, I was looking how to do something similar to Stackoverflow's code thing:

e.g. The "var" is colored and "test" isn't

```
var test
```

How would I write a JavaScript function to do this?

This is what I tried

```
if ("var")  {
document.getElementByTagName("code").style.color="purple";
}
```

So when the text "var" is in a "code" element, it turns JUST "var" purple.

Comment: You are in a wrong way right now. You should improve your html and javascript knowledge first before trying do this thing , because you are stucked in wrong concepts that im my option will retard your learning.

Comment: @Wagner Thanks,  I'm pretty familiar with HTML and CSS, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it faster with JavaScript.

Comment: If you're actually looking to do proper syntax highlighting, it's a lot more complex than that. It would either have to be a very complicated regular expression (for most common forms of syntax - still doesn't work fully) or you'd have to tokenise your characters into an AST and map the relevant parts to the original code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the variable name in a span

```
<code>
  var <span class="variable-name">test</span>
</code>
```

Then color just the span, jQuery makes this easier

```
$('code span.variable-name').css('color', 'purple');
```

**However,** There are also syntax highlighting libraries that would make this whole thing easier since it's largely a solved problem :) [**Here is an example**](http://craig.is/making/rainbows/)

Comment: Doing it yourself would require implementing a decent chunk of a lexer, so a library is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I was looking to do it without an extra HTML.  Is this possible?

Comment: Certainly possible, I would look into a syntax highlighting library like: http://craig.is/making/rainbows/

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I assume you accepted because of my comment above. ^

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty (emphasis on dirty) way to do it with regex replace if:

1. You don't care about actually parsing the syntax
2. You know the code elements only contain clean text, no child tags

If that's so, you can do something like:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('code'),
    code;

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    code = els[i].innerHTML;
    els[i].innerHTML = code.replace(
        /\bvar\b/g,
        '<span style="color: #f00;">var</span>'
    );
}
```

Yes, it's better practice to use a class instead of inline style, but seeing as not following the above two points is also bad practice, this is just for example's sake.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w272h/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML and js element

```
 <div>
   var test;
 </div>


<script>
 var varText = $( "div" ).text().split( " " ).join( "</span> <span>" );
 newText = "<span>" + varText + "</span>";

$( "div" )
.html( varText )
.find( "span" )
.end()
.find( ":contains('var')" )
.css({
  "color": "purple",

});
```